# MPRemoteCommandCenter does not work with Bluetooth Handsfree

Tags: ios, bluetooth, mpremotecommandcenter

I want to receive remote control events from Bluetooth Handsfree device, Below mentioned is my set of code for play and pause events.

```
MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().nextTrackCommand.isEnabled = true
MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().previousTrackCommand.isEnabled = true
MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().nextTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playCommand))
MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().previousTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(previousCommand))
```

But no such events are triggered. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

in

```
viewWillAppear()
```

in order to make your application get the desired events.